# PL/SQL: Hashing of numbers by groups

Tags: plsql

The question is as follows:

As you know, in the Oracle database, 'NUMBER' type has a length limit of 38 characters. I have a method that hashing numbers from a table. Due to the above restriction, I have problems with this method: how to increase the length of the hashing values?

The idea was to make a method-wrapper that will hashing by groups. (from 1 to 38 number, then from 39, etc.) It is acceptable if the value is text (VARCHAR2). But I have to get a number on the way out.

In plsql I am a beginner, so I want to ask more experienced people, what can I do in this situation? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `But I have to get a number on the way out` ... What is the destination after you take the hashes out of Oracle?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Method put the hash back into the table instead of the normal value

Comment: The limit is 38 decimal digits of precision, not 38 characters. You can store larger numbers up to 9.99e125 but they lose precision.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson You're right. Sorry, I didn't put it right.

Comment: If the data you wish to store is the result of a hash function, there's probably not much need to store it as a number - you're not going to do arithmetic on it, after all. You may as well store it in a `VARCHAR2` which can store up to 4000 digits if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Initially, I already had some function that could hash number's up to 38 (***hash_number***). I wrote a this wrapper function. Maybe someone will be useful this code:

```
function hash_to_long_number(p_in number) return varchar2 is
    p_in_copy varchar2(4000) := p_in;
    buffer varchar2(4000);
    result varchar2(4000);

    accuracy number := 38;

    begin
        while length(p_in_copy) >= 0
        loop
            if (length(p_in_copy) > accuracy) then
                buffer := substr(p_in_copy, 1, accuracy);
                p_in_copy := substr(p_in_copy, length(buffer) + 1, length(p_in_copy));
            else
                buffer := p_in_copy;
                p_in_copy := substr(p_in_copy, length(buffer) + 1, length(p_in_copy));
            end if;

            buffer := hash_number(buffer, length(buffer));
            result := result || buffer;
        end loop;
        return result;
    end hash_to_long_number_by_key;
```